# Convert Week number to date in data frame

Tags: r, lubridate

I have the below dataset

```
  Week Year 
  1    2019
  2    2019
  1    2020 
  2    2020
```

I wish to add a column that shows the start date of the week (starting on Sunday)

So, my ideal output would be

```
  Week Year Date 
  1    2019 06/01/2019
  2    2019 13/01/2019
  1    2020 05/01/2020
  2    2020 12/01/2010
```

I have tried the below solution

```
library (lubridate) 
if (df$Year ==2019) {df$Date = parse_date_time(paste(2019, df$Week, 'Sun', sep=" "),'Y/W/a')}
if (df$Year ==2019) {df$Date = parse_date_time(paste(2020, df$Week, 'Sun', sep=" "),'Y/W/a')}
```

However, I got the warning message that "failed to parse". Any tips would be appreciated

Comment: 3rd and 4th row is same in your data but their output is different.

Comment: Thanks Ronak, I just revised it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in base R using `as.Date` itself.

Based on your attempt it seems your locale is English, so you can try :

```
as.Date(paste(df$Week, df$Year, 'Sun'), '%U %Y %a')
#[1] "2019-01-06" "2019-01-13" "2020-01-05" "2020-01-05"
```

Comment: for me it produces "NA"s. not sure why

Comment: That is strange. It works for me as shown though. Are you sure your locale is English and not anything else?

Comment: Avoid potential locale issues by using `%w` instead ("Weekday as decimal number (0–6, Sunday is 0") (also described in the link I posted)